R Tidyverse recursive function path creation issue
In the context of the bill of materials, I have a tree structure and I want to perform a recursive function to find the different paths of this tree.
I did, however, a mistake when trying to define a path for materials that are shared by sub-assemblies. This problem was previously solved using the updated code below. However, this code does not work anymore as expected to get the expected result below when I use the new dataset where the material has NA values for the materials which are the finished goods (roots). Please check the dataset below and help me find out how to adjust again the function to fit this requirement.
Here is my bom structure:
BOM <- tibble(
bomID = 1:24,
finiGoodID = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 12)), 
matID = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 
          NA , 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 5, 6),
parentMatID = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 
                NA, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 11, 13, 13))

Now the function is:
bomPath <- function(mat, p, fg) {
row <- subset(BOM, matID == mat & parentMatID == p & finiGoodID == fg)
if (nrow(row) == 0) {
    return(mat)
}
if (is.na(p)) {
    return(mat)
} else {
    # Recursively build the path
    rownew <- subset(BOM, matID == p & finiGoodID == fg)
    parent_path <- sapply(rownew$parentMatID, \(x) bomPath(p, x, fg))
    return(c(mat, parent_path))
}

}
I call this function this way:
for (i in 1:nrow(BOM)) {
path = bomPath(BOM$matID[i], BOM$finiGoodID[i])
print(path)
}

I wanted to create something simple but the results are shown like:
[1] 1
[1] 2 1
[1] 3 2 1
[1] 4 2 1
[1] 5 4 2 1
[1] 6 4 2 1
[1] 7 4 2 1
[1] 8 4 2 1
[1] 9 4 2 1
[1] 10  1
[1] 5 4 2 1 #This was supposed to be [1] 5 3 2 1
[1] 6 4 2 1 #This was supposed to be [1] 6 3 2 1
[1] 11
[1] 12 11
[1] 13 12 11
[1] 14 12 11
[1] 15 14 12 11
[1] 16 14 12 11
[1] 17 14 12 11
[1] 18 14 12 11
[1] 19 14 12 11
[1] 20 11
[1]  5 13 12 11
[1]  6 13 12 11

Any idea for how to solve this? I will derive calculations based on this path definition.

If you prefer to stick with base R recursion, you can make a minor modification on your function, like below
bomPath <- function(mat, p, fg) {
    row <- subset(BOM, matID == mat & parentMatID == p & finiGoodID == fg)
    if (nrow(row) == 0) {
        return(mat)
    }
    if (is.na(p)) {
        return(mat)
    } else {
        # Recursively build the path
        rownew <- subset(BOM, matID == p & finiGoodID == fg)
        parent_path <- sapply(rownew$parentMatID, \(x) bomPath(p, x, fg))
        return(c(mat, parent_path))
    }
}

then run
for (i in 1:nrow(BOM)) {
    path <- bomPath(BOM$matID[i], BOM$parentMatID[i], BOM$finiGoodID[i])
    print(path)
}

and you will see
[1] 1
[1] 2 1
[1] 3 2 1
[1] 4 2 1
[1] 5 4 2 1
[1] 6 4 2 1
[1] 7 4 2 1
[1] 8 4 2 1
[1] 9 4 2 1
[1] 10  1
[1] 5 3 2 1
[1] 6 3 2 1
[1] 11
[1] 12 11
[1] 13 12 11
[1] 14 12 11
[1] 15 14 12 11
[1] 16 14 12 11
[1] 17 14 12 11
[1] 18 14 12 11
[1] 19 14 12 11
[1] 20 11
[1]  5 13 12 11
[1]  6 13 12 11


Another handy option is using igraph
library(igraph)
dfs <- with(BOM, split(data.frame(matID, parentMatID), finiGoodID))
unlist(
    lapply(
        dfs,
        \(x) {
            g <- x %>%
                mutate(parentMatID = coalesce(parentMatID, matID)) %>%
                graph_from_data_frame() %>%
                simplify()
            src <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "out") == 0]
            lapply(
                shortest_paths(g, src, as.character(x$matID), mode = "in")$vpath,
                \(p) {
                    as.integer(names(rev(p)))
                }
            )
        }
    ),
    FALSE,
    FALSE
)

which could give
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 3 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 4 2 1

[[5]]
[1] 5 3 2 1

[[6]]
[1] 6 3 2 1

[[7]]
[1] 7 4 2 1

[[8]]
[1] 8 4 2 1

[[9]]
[1] 9 4 2 1

[[10]]
[1] 10  1

[[11]]
[1] 5 3 2 1

[[12]]
[1] 6 3 2 1

[[13]]
[1] 11

[[14]]
[1] 12 11

[[15]]
[1] 13 12 11

[[16]]
[1] 14 12 11

[[17]]
[1] 15 14 12 11

[[18]]
[1] 16 14 12 11

[[19]]
[1] 17 14 12 11

[[20]]
[1] 18 14 12 11

[[21]]
[1] 19 14 12 11

[[22]]
[1] 20 11

[[23]]
[1]  5 13 12 11

[[24]]
[1]  6 13 12 11


Thank you! however I want to keep it simple using R-tidyverse without graph reprasentation. I just need to update my path finder function

Thank you very much!! it works now. I will try to make recursive calculations using this pathfinder and will ask back if anything doesn't turn right

Now what if the material that is representing the finished good is NA? like:
BOM <- tibble(
bomID = 1:24,
finiGoodID = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 12)),
matID = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6,
NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 5, 6),
parentMatID = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3,
NA, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 11, 13, 13),)
